# replace \u0087 with "" using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in an Excel sheet that has been downloaded by a Power Query and there are `\u0087` characters

[image]

I am trying to replace the character `\u0087` with `""` with VBA:

```
.Replace "‡", ""
.Replace "u0087", ""
.Replace what:=Chr(135), replacement:=""
```

But it is not replacing even though this method work fine for other characters like Em-Dash

```
.Replace what:="–", replacement:="-"
.Replace what:=Chr(150), replacement:=Chr(45)
```

Why this is not working? How to make it work

Comment: `ChrW$(135)`?..

Comment: Try replacement:="""" ?

Comment: @SpectralInstance To replace with a quote?

Comment: replace with null,essentially I want to delete it

Comment: Yes `ChrW$(135)` did it. Thank you GSerg

Comment: You could just replace it in your Power Query.

Comment: @ronrosenfeld How would I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to do it in **Power Query**, you just need to select your column in the Power Query Editor and go to Transform -> Replace Values -> Replace Values.

On value to find, add your symbol: ‡

On Replace With, keep it blank as it is.  Then click ok.

Your code will be like `= Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"‡","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"})` and the result in my example is the following.

[image]

---

If you still prefer to use VBA, this code works for me: `ActiveCell.Replace What:="‡", Replacement:=""`